# В форме обратной связи не отправляется прикрепленный файл

Tags: php

Пытался создать форму обратной связи с сайта. Прочитал кучу книг по PHP, скачал кучу обработчиков событий. Но так и не добился, что бы прикрепленный файл отправлялся на e-mail. Все поля формы работают отлично, кроме одного. Специалисты, подскажите, где ошибка? Заранее спасибо.

И еще. Класс class.phpmailer.php имеется на сервере или его надо устанавливать?

Файл формы:

```
<div align="center" id="mail_form"><br><br>
<form method="post" action="formmail.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name=recipient value="f@mmm.com">
<input type="hidden" name="subject" value="in-Site">
 <table width="800">
  <tr><td height="20"></td></tr>
  <tr><td align="center">
   <fieldset title="Обязательные поля">
   <legend aligen="left">Форма сообщения</legend>
<table>
 <tr><td height="10"></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
 <tr><td align="right"><label for="opinion-file">Прикрепленный файл:&nbsp;&nbsp;</label></td><td width="20"></td><td><input type="file" name="opinion-file" size="75"></td></tr>
 <tr><td height="10"></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
 <tr><td align="right" valign="top">Сообщение:</td><td width="20"></td><td><textarea cols="61" rows="10" name="message"></textarea></td></tr>
 <tr><td height="10"></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
</table>
 <input type="submit" value="Отправить сообщение">
 <input type="reset" value="Очистить форму">
   </fieldset><br>
  </td></tr>
 </table>
</form>
</div>
```

Внешний обработчик событий:

```
<?php

function complete_mail() {
    $_POST['title'] =  substr(htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['title'])), 0, 1000);
    $_POST['mess'] =  substr(htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['mess'])), 0, 1000000);
    $_POST['name'] =  substr(htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['name'])), 0, 30);
    $_POST['tel'] =  substr(htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['tel'])), 0, 30);
    $_POST['email'] =  substr(htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['email'])), 0, 50);
    // если не заполнено поле "Имя" - показываем ошибку 0
    if (empty($_POST['name']))
         output_err(0);
    // если неправильно заполнено поле email - показываем ошибку 1
    if(!preg_match("/[0-9a-z_]+@[0-9a-z_^\.]+\.[a-z]{2,3}/i", $_POST['email']))
         output_err(1);
    // если не заполнено поле "Сообщение" - показываем ошибку 2
    if(empty($_POST['mess']))
         output_err(2);
    // обратите внимание, теперь мы можем писать красивые письма, с помощью html тегов ;-)
    $mess = '
<b>Имя отправителя:</b>'.$_POST['name'].'<br />
<b>Контактный телефон:</b>'.$_POST['tel'].'<br />
<b>Контактный email:</b>'.$_POST['email'].'<br />
'.$_POST['mess'];

    // подключаем файл класса для отправки почты
    require 'class.phpmailer.php';

    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->From = 'test@test.ru';      // от кого
    $mail->FromName = 'www.php-mail.ru';   // от кого
    $mail->AddAddress('to@yandex.ru', 'Имя'); // кому - адрес, Имя
    $mail->IsHTML(true);        // выставляем формат письма HTML
    $mail->Subject = $_POST['title'];  // тема письма

    // если был файл, то прикрепляем его к письму
    if(isset($_FILES['attachfile'])) {
             if($_FILES['attachfile']['error'] == 0){
                $mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['attachfile']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['attachfile']['name']);
             }
    }
    // если было изображение, то прикрепляем его в виде картинки к телу письма.
    if(isset($_FILES['attachimage'])) {
             if($_FILES['attachimage']['error'] == 0){
                if (!$mail->AddEmbeddedImage($_FILES['attachimage']['tmp_name'], 'my-attach', 'image.gif', 'base64', $_FILES['attachimage']['type']))
                     die ($mail->ErrorInfo);
                $mess .= 'А вот и наша картинка:<br /><img src="cid:my-attach" border=0><br />я показал как ее прикреплять, соответственно Вам осталось вставить ее в нужное место Вашего письма ;-) ';
             }
    }
    $mail->Body = $mess;

    // отправляем наше письмо
    if (!$mail->Send()) die ('Mailer Error: '.$mail->ErrorInfo);
    echo 'Спасибо! Ваше письмо отправлено. В течении одних суток с Вами свяжутся представители компании.';
}

function output_err($num)
{
    $err[0] = 'ОШИБКА! Не введено имя.';
    $err[1] = 'ОШИБКА! Неверно введен e-mail.';
    $err[2] = 'ОШИБКА! Не введено сообщение.';
    echo '<p>'.$err[$num].'</p>';
    show_form();
    exit();
}

if (!empty($_POST['submit'])) complete_mail();
else show_form();
?>
```

Comment: `<input type="file" name="opinion-file" size="75">` поменяйте `name` на `attachfile`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

class.phpmailer.php нужно залить на сервер и положить рядом со скриптом который отсылает почтовое сообщение. После этого всё должно заработать. Возможно, придется устновить права на запись в папку которую загружается файл перед его отправкой, за это отвечает AddAttachment.

Comment: Такую запись?

   <IfModule mod_charset.c>
    CharsetRecodeMultipartForms off
   </IfModule>

Comment: Спасибо за совет. Нашел запись для AddAttachment

    $mailer->AddAttachment('/home/mywebsite/public_html/file.zip', 'file.zip');

Comment: Строку с путем лучше заменить на $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] и загружать файл не в корень сайта как сейчас, а в отведенную для этого папку с правами на запись. Далее, нужно проверять что за файл загружается, не давая загружать, наприрме, *.php файлы - это серьёзнейшая угроза безопасности. И на последок, после отправки сообщения файл нужно удалить из папки. Как то так.